# Fetch records if field exists in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this query

```
db.invites.find({$and: [{primaryowner: mynumber}, {invited: mynumber}]})
```

which i am using to fetch records if they satisfy the conditions above.However, i would like to fetch records where `{eventtype:4}` and the field `primaryowner:$exists: true`

This is what i have

```
{ eventtype: 4 },{ primaryowner: { $exists: true }}
```

but i know this is not it because i need to fetch records where `eventtype = 4` and the field `primaryowner` exists.

How can i represent the query?.

Comment: Are you asking for `db.invites.find({$and: [{eventtype: 4}, { primaryowner: { $exists: true }}]})`? You question is really not clear...

Comment: Post your sample document and your expected output here

Comment: @ClementAmarnath This is my statement `db.invites.find({invited:"0800123456",{$and: [{eventtype: "4"},{primaryowner: { $exists: true }}]}.pretty()` i am expecting to get records where invited is 0800123456 and the eventtype = 4 where that row has a field primaryowner

Comment: are you getting the expected response? also post a sample document from your collection

Comment: @ClementAmarnath Okay,i am posting some data .

Comment: @ClementAmarnath I posted a detailed question here in dba, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151954/combining-query-results-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I couldnot clearly understand what is the required business scenario, but with the sample data provided
I have given an pseudo code and the respective mongodb implementation of that pseudo code.

```
if invited field is "0800123456" 
   if event type is 3 and event status is 11
     select matching documents
or if event type is 4 and event status is 11 and primary owner exists
     select matching documents
```

Mongo DB Query

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          "invited": "0800123456"
        },
        {
          "eventtype": {
            $eq: "3"
          }
        },
        {
          "eventstatus": {
            $eq: 11
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          "eventtype": {
            $eq: "4"
          }
        },
        {
          "eventstatus": {
            $eq: 11
          }
        },
        {
          primaryowner: {
            $exists: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

If this is not matching your scenario, then write your own query with the help of this sample code.

Hope it Helps!